Are you more likely to see an aurora a week before or a week after the equinox?
Around the equinoxes the chances of seeing auroras are higher. Are you more likely to see an aurora if you go a week before or a week after the equinox?

Why do you think aurorae are more prevalent around the equinox? How does that affect solar activity?

@Chenmunka see this:https://www.hurtigruten.com/en-us/inspiration/northern-lights/science

The effect is fairly weak.  I would concentrate mostly on weather conditions and solar activity.

@GregMiller solar activity is critical, but weather is also a key consideration – e.g. in most places skies are most likely to be cloudless in mid to late autumn. Another key element is darkness; after the autumn equinox nights are longer than days, so it's a useful reference point for increased viewing hours.

The reasons for the seasonal effect. https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/58397/seasonal-variation-of-aurora-and-magnetic-activity?noredirect=1&lq=1

Probably the week after is a better bet. According to this compilation of 92 years of data on auroras, many of the most geomagnetically active days of the year are in the week after the vernal or autumnal equinox, with none in the week before it. While there isn't data there for the exact 1 week afterwards, I think it's safe to assume that it would be higher than 1 week before.

Thank you for your answer :) I don’t have access to upvote yet…
